# why is out.println as short as you can go?

Tags: java

why is it that you can shorten java's system.out.println to out.println via static import of java.lang.system.out, but you cannot shorten it further to simply println?

Comment: because println is no static method of PrintStream?

Comment: who says you cant ? just define your own println function ?

Comment: @Berger Not quite correct. You can also statically import static inner classes and static fields. Might be forgetting some others...

Answer (score 0):

out is static instance of a class inside System class but println is just a non static method